# How do i remove distorted vertices inside of my 3D object?

Tags: mesh, sculpting

I used mirror to make a character body from skin mesh and applyes some subdivisions

my character look like this now 
[image]

[image]

i tried to use cleand up but no sucess, someone can help me ? how can i make this smooth ?

sorry for my english ppl

Comment: you could delete all this part and try a Grid Fill, but are you sure you need so many faces? It doesn't make things easier

Comment: Maybe decimating ? i am working with sculpt because of this i have so many faces

Comment: there are several ways to simplify a mesh, you can try to reduce the amount of faces by several methods (for example try a simple ctrl E > Un-subdivide), or retopologize, but if you want to do so, it's a completely different question that needs a completely different answer.